# Switching between English and Swedish keyboard on Ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, keyboard-layout

How can I switch between English and Swedish keyboard on my Ubuntu 13.04?

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. The trick here is that this is called "keyboard layout" in Linux speak. So, if you google for "add keyboard layout ubuntu 13.04" you'll find tons of examples. Hope this helps...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Click on the system settings.

Select keyboard icon

There is a link at the down left of the window called "Layout Settings"

Click + to add the input source layout

Select Swedish from the list and Click Add button.

There is also a checkbox to display the input source at the system tray and a shortcut at the same window.